# .removeClass for more than one cached selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, caching

Working on optimising some js/jQuery code by caching selectors where they're used more than once to help speed things up e.g:

```
var object = $("#object");
object.removeClass('class-name');
```

i've run into trouble chaining the cached selectors though, here's my attempt:

```
var object1 = $("#object1");
var object2 = $("#object2");
$(object1, object2).removeClass('class-name');
```

This works for the first cached element but not the second, any ideas on the correct syntax?
I've searched for it but can't seem to find anything!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

```
object1.add(object2).removeClass('class-name');
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks!
I'll set yours as the answer once the 10 minute time restriction is up.
What about if there are more than 2 cached selectors though?

Comment: @JacobBanner, You can keep on using `add()` like `object1.add(object2).add(object3)`

Answer (score 1):

Satpal answer is pretty straight forward but if you want an alternative(to handle more classes and not to end with a huge jquery chain) you can keep jquery objects in an array and using an iteration:

```js
"use strict";
var arr = [];
var object1 = $("#object1");
var object2 = $("#object2");
arr.push(object1, object2)
for (var e of arr) {
  e.removeClass("class-name");
}
```

```css
.class-name {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="object1" class="class-name">this</div>
<div id="object2" class="class-name">this</div>
<div id="object3" class="class-name">this</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using these two selectors together is another option that you can use:

```
$('#object1, #object2').removeClass('class-name');
```

Comment: I might be wrong wrong but i think that references the elements themselves, not the cached selectors which presents no performance gains

Comment: Oh yes, it is my fault. I learned now, this is not a solution for caching selectors.

Comment: Thanks for answering anyway dude! :)